# jQuery 'click' automatically fires 'live'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simple piece of code:

HTML:

```
<div id="close">Click me</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$("#close").click(function(){
    alert("1");
    $(this).attr('id','expand');
});



$("#expand").live('click', function(){
    alert("2");
    $(this).attr('id','close');            
});
```

Problem: When I click on "close" it automatically calls live() too. See this in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uFJkg/

Is it because I am changing the same element's id from "close" to "expand"? How do I fix this problem?

I have tried:

```
 $("#expand").die().live('click', function()
```

but it didn't work. I tried event.stopPropagation() but that didn't help too. I tried having a separate div with id "expand" and hide it on document.ready but for some reason it is not working too.

Then I have tried since I read that live() has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7+:

```
$("#expand").on('click', function(){
```

and that is not working too.

Any thoughts? I think a fresh set of eyes will be able to spot what I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you `return true;` from your first click function?

Comment: You're adding two handlers for the same event, yes?

Comment: Yeah but I am changing the id of the div. Wouldn't that be considered as a different event then?

@Platinum: I am using the on() instead of live() and it is not even being called now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need both delegate event *(aka live)* handler in this case. Because, you're toggling between both `id`s and this toggling make both `id`s as dynamic to DOM.

```
$("body").on("click", "#close", function(){
    alert("1");
    $(this).attr('id','expand');
});

$("body").on("click", "#expand", function(){
    alert("2");
    $(this).attr('id','close');            
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uFJkg/1/)***

### Note

As `live()` is ***[deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)***, so instead of `live()` use ***[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)*** for delegate event handling.

Comment: Perfectly worked. Thanks a lot :)!!! I think I tried live() for both the events but I didn't try on(). Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the way `live` attaches events and how event bubbling works.

`.live` attaches event handlers to the `document`. When the document registers an event, it looks to see what the `target` of that event is. If it matches the selector passed to `.live`, it fires the handler.

So, when you click on `#close`, this is what happens:

1. click event registered on `#close`, handler fires.
2. `#close` is changed to `#expand`
3. click event bubbles up the DOM until it reaches the `document`
4. click event registers on `document`, document sees that the ID of the target element is `#expand`, and it fires the event handler

The way to solve this is to add `stopPropagation()` to your handlers:

```
$("#close").click(function(e){
  if(!e) { e = window.event; }
  e.stopPropagation();

  alert("1");
  $(this).attr('id','expand');
});
```

However, I would recommend not using `live` and looking into `delegate` or `on` to handle delegated events.

I would also recommend against changing the ID. I would try something like this if you want to keep the close/expand idea:

```
<div id="toggler" class="close">Close</div>

$('#toggler').on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('close').toggleClass('expand');
});
```

One event handler, no delegation because it hooks into the permanent ID

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not very clean to change your id's runtime. You're facing one of the results of that.

You might consider using the data-attributes. jQuery can read them by accessing the data property.

Eg.

```
$("#myObject").data("expanded", true);
```

In that way it's not necessary to change your id's.